# Directional light causes an FPS drop

Tags: unity, shaders, performance, lighting

I have only one object in the scene and it is lit with a directional light. It uses the mobile/diffuse shader. The issue is that on iPhone 4 the FPS drops from ~42FPS to ~11FPS when the directional light is enabled. Rendering is set to forward rendering and there are no other light sources. Shadows are not enabled.

Scene stats give a total of five draw calls, 3k tris and 2.6k verts. Having a single directional light should not have that kind of effect on FPS. What could cause this FPS drop?

[image]

Comment: if you have one material with a single directional light, no shadow received nor casted, you should have exactly one drawcall if you use mobile/diffuse.

Comment: this sounds strange. could you explain a bit more about your code behind drawing the sceene? and also show the shader code?+

Comment: You might want to try setting the shader to "Mobile/VertexLit (Only Directional Lights)". See http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/198158/optimize-game-for-iphone-4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after spending hours to figure out why it did that, it turned out to be rather simple. Even though the rendering was set to `Forward` in the player settings it was overridden to `Deferred` in the camera itself.

[image]

This caused more draw calls than it should have, as @Heisenbug pointed out, and the very poor performance as the iPhone4 is nowhere near capable to use deferred.